# Filter posts by advanced custom field

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

How I can create filter which will filter posts by one custom field - year?

Field name: year

Field type: number

I need to setup some dropdown in page with existing values.

For example in 3 posts I'll enter some years(2017, 2016, 2015 etc.) and I need to display dropdown in page with 3 values - 2017, 2016, 2015.

I'm using this code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');

function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
if( is_admin() ) {
    return;
}

$year= $query->get('meta_query');
if( !empty($_GET['year']) ) {
    $lerge = array(
        'key'       => 'year',
        'value'     => '2017',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    );
}

$query->set('meta_query', $year);
return;
}
```

And if I go to

```
?year=2017
```

I'm getting 404 page not found